# How to performe like shell to show the lastest input when press up key

Tags: perl

I wrote a small program to read input, and print the result, and loop. Like `REPL`.

And I want to get the input I have inputed before when I press the up key on the keyboard and edit this input, like what `bash` or `zsh` does. I have no idea about the implementation. I also searched the web but no result I want. Could someone point a way for me? Or give me some articles to read?

The point is: How to print an EDITABLE line on screen?

Answer (score 4):

I have no personal experience with it, but it's my understanding that [Term::ReadLine](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Term%3a%3aReadLine) provides command editing functionality with history. It's even part of the `perl` distribution.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to:

- Store a history of user input, just like bash and zsh do;
- Listen for <kbd>↑</kbd> key presses, just like bash and zsh do;
- Display the last command when <kbd>↑</kbd> is pressed. Just like, you guessed it, bash and zsh.

*This is what programming is all about:* breaking down big problems we don't know how to solve into smaller problems that we *do* know how to solve, or can more-easily figure out how to solve. So if you don't know how to do any of the things I listed above, try writing some code, reading API documentation, looking for answers on Google/Stack Overflow, or – once again – breaking them down into sub-problems.

Comment: @squiguy `*gasp*` `</sarcasm>`

Comment: Howdy Matt. I'll get a editable history line when I using zsh. But how to print an editable line here in @Laurent's repl? I think he know how to print an uneditable line.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

if your point is "**print**" maybe you need Term::Screen.  example code here: [code](http://forum.ubuntu.org.cn/viewtopic.php?f=21&t=194771).

otherwise if your point is "**history**",  man/perldoc Term::ReadLine.

Comment: I want to print the last input editable, I think "**print**" is the point, because I can store the history myself. Your example code is too long, I will see the Term::Screen on CPAN. And, thankyou very much. :)